# How to make the foreground subject transparent?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png

I know that there's a lot of tutorials on how to make the background transparent. But I can't find any on how to make the foreground transparent. 
These transparent checkerboxes should be on the t-shirt but the background would remain white

here's my expanded layers file:
https://prnt.sc/sde79s

Here's what I mean: https://prnt.sc/sde6qp

Comment: Unless I'm missing something ....Simply use a "background removal" tutorial and reverse the removal. It's all the same methodology. You simply have to **think** of the shirt as the *background* and the white as the *foreground*.

Comment: Oh.. yeah why didn't I think of that. Sorry, thought there was different method to this.

Comment: You can invert the layer masks.

Comment: This question is not the same on the surface, but you are both trying to achieve the same end-result: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/120948/2332

Answer (score 1):

1. Follow a tutorial to make the background transparent using selections.
2. Invert the selection.
3. Done.

Answer (score -1):

incase you are using Photoshop artboards 
If you want to change the background of your artboard to transparent, follow these instructions:
Click the artboard.
Go to the Properties panel (Window > Properties) for the artboard.
Under artboard background color, select the background and change it to transparent.